# How to Properly Call an Await Method in Main?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TaskConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {       
             test();    
        }

        static async Task<string> ReadTextAsync() 
        {
            string textContents;
            Task<string> readFromText;

            using (StreamReader reader =  File.OpenText("email.txt"))
            {
                readFromText = reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                textContents = await readFromText;

            }

            return textContents;     
        }

        static async Task test ()
        {
            string capture = await ReadTextAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(capture);
        }               
    }               
}
```

I have the following code to read from a text file using async. I learned from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114848/why-do-some-async-methods-require-a-return-type-of-task-and-others-dont) that the example that Microsoft implemented using StreamReader is incorrect, so as a learning exercise, I decided to correct it. How would I properly call the test method from main, when the test method doesn't return any task. I did a little reading and learned it's bad practice to use async void. In my case what should I do?

Side Note: I don't know if I implemented it wrong, but I can't get my text to display. I tried it the non-async way and it worked, however, when I use async it shows blank, and Please Press Any Key to Continue"

Comment: Why would you want to do this asynchronously as you are waiting for it anyway and making it synchronous? A lot of effort to achieve default synchronous flow?

Comment: @Belogix - No particular reason, as I said in the above post, Microsoft implemented it wrong, so as a learning exercise, I decided to correct it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [async at console app in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630506/async-at-console-app-in-c)

Comment: You do not need to have the await in both places.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167934/how-to-async-files-readalllines-and-await-for-results

Comment: @Belogix - What else should I do it make it asynchronous?

Comment: @ShawnMHolman - How would you correct it, so that await isn't in both places?

Answer (score 5):

> How would I properly call the test method from main, when the test
>   method doesn't return any task.

Because `Main` can't be modified to be `async`, you'll have to explictly call `Task.Wait` on it:

```
Test().Wait();
```

This is the *only place* you should be blocking on an async call.

Comment: in a WPF I should be calling from an async method correct?

Comment: @Nexusfactor In WPF you should be using `await Test()`.

Comment: According to a commenter above, I don't need await in both place, just for my own understanding, how would you correct it?

Answer (score 0):

```
static async Task<string> ReadTextAsync() 
        {
            string textContents;
            Task<string> readFromText;

            using (StreamReader reader =  File.OpenText("email.txt"))
            {
                readFromText = await Task.Run(() => reader != null ? reader.ReadToEndAsync() : null);
                textContents = readFromText;

            }

            return textContents;     
        }

        static Task test ()
        {
            string capture = ReadTextAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(capture);
        }
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, the way I was doing it previously, is it the incorrect way? What is the downside of doing it the way I was doing it as opposed to the way you've shown?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013523/when-correctly-use-task-run-and-when-just-async-await